# NodeJs: Parsing POST request file upload as stream to ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, fs, formidable

I'm trying to upload a file by sending a POST request to my NodeJs-server where the server will upon receiving the request (but not necessarily whole file) create a readStream on the incoming file and pass it to `fluent-ffmpeg` for video-compression and then saving it on the server. The idea is to pass the stream to ffmpeg without waiting for the whole file to be uploaded instead of waiting for the upload to complete and then pass the file since it would take more time and require to store the file temporarily on the server before the compression.

With the current code ffmpeg gives the error `pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input` which I translate to some error with the stream creation. The code is as follows

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
  let formidable = require('formidable');
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(files.uploadedfile.path);
    let ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
    let ffmpegCmd = ffmpeg(readStream)
    ...
  });
});
```

Am I making some wrong assumption here?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured? I'm attempting to do something similar

Comment: @Antoine I think I partially got it to work with streams. The issue is that for some file formats important data is stored at the end of the file (such as length) and if it is read as a stream that data will not be available in ffmpeg. Instead I stored the file in each step before passing it to the next. While this is less optimal it solves the issue. Do let me know if you manage to get this to work!

Comment: @ChristianAbdelmassih would you be able to show your answer - as this could be useful for others

Comment: @RussellHarrower as in my reply from 2017 i only managed to get this to work for video files where the metadata is stored in the beginning of the file, not the cases if it is stored at the end which most of the files I worked with had. To understand why this is a thing, refer to https://sanjeev-pandey.medium.com/understanding-the-mpeg-4-moov-atom-pseudo-streaming-in-mp4-93935e1b9e9a.


Because I found no solution, I ended up uploading the whole file to the server before passing it through ffmpeg.

Unfortunately I do no longer have access to the code base.

Comment: @ChristianAbdelmassih now that makes sense - uploading it to the server first, then do the processing and then upload to S3 or database.